# Eigenvalue of a form

Tags: linear-algebra, several-complex-variables

I came across the following matrix while reading an article..Can you please help me to understand the following.

We are defining  following form:
$$\sum_{i,j}\partial_{z_i}\partial_{\bar{z_j}}rdz_i\otimes d\bar{z_j}$$

Where $r: M(\subset \mathbb C^2) \to \mathbb R$ is $C^2$ function.

1-  Where this form acts[Domain]; I think  $dz_i\otimes d\bar{z_i}$ should act on  $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C$.  But how does it act.. etc.

2-  What does mean by eigen value of this form, what is typical eigen vector..

i am sorry if question are trivial... but can someone help me.

Comment: Hi Junu, what is your background with tensor products? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product

Comment: @tentaclenorm, I know that $dz_i\otimes d\bar{z_i}$ should act on  $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C$.  But how does it act.. etc.. i think, i know a bit of tensor.. but i am confused..